# Serenity JUnit tests are not getting executed in parallel with LambdaTest Maven Tunnel

Tags: java, junit4, serenity-bdd, lambdatest

I am using all these dependencies in the POM.xml for my serenity project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SerenityBDD</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <serenity.version>3.6.12</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>3.6.12</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>3.6.12</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
        <tags></tags>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.lambdatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdatest-tunnel-binary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/SerenityTestRunner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/SerenityRunner*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>3</threadCount>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.26.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tags>${tags}</tags>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

After commenting the LambdaTest Maven Tunnel dependency, the parallel execution of tests on LambdaTest dashboard works fine.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.lambdatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdatest-tunnel-binary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Debugging Steps:

- To execute all the tests in parallel threads with LambdaTest Maven Tunnel on LambdaTest grid.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maven tunnel dependency is below as per your pom details
https://github.com/LambdaTest/lambdatest-maven-tunnel

this is using testng as dependency.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
   </dependency>
```

It could give you some issues when running with surefire. try with TestNG Exclusion as below. It should work.
It is always the better idea to use latest version.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.lambdatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambdatest-tunnel-binary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```